# feathersjs - Custom create method in service

Tags: feathersjs

I need some help. I need to insert other objects when I call e.g. a item service create method. But I don't know how to achieve this in the service class of the item model.

I got a database table where I need to store an Id of another table entry, but first I need to insert this entry.

And I want to this this with one call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's simple. Use the feathers CLI to generate a custom service.